# Hash iteration while multiplying current value by successive value

Tags: ruby

I have this hash:

```
myhash = { 1=> 2,  2=> 18, 3=> 8,
           4=> 22, 5=> 34, 6=> 16 }
```

I will pass a number to my method, that checks if any two successive values in the hash multiplied, will match that number.

Example: 
Number is 748, so the iteration should be 2 * 18, 18 * 8, 8 * 22, 22 * 34, 34 * 16.  The correct answer would be the hash values of 22 and 34.

One of the ways I've tried to get this to work

```
l = myhash.length - 1
product = 748
myhash.take(l).keep_if.each_with_index { |k,v| myhash[v] * myhash[v+1] == product }
```

Surprisingly this is throwing an `undefined method`*' for nil:NilClass` .  I say surprisingly because I've used that kind of multiplying in another place with success.

I'm taking it though as the [v+1] maybe empty and I'm using the wrong syntax.
What I would like to accomplish though and I've tried both 'select' and 'keep_if', is to have the hash return both key / value pairs. Example in this case - 
`[[4, 23][5, 34]`.

Another thing I tried that was more promising was to use an if statement and then capture the two values over to another array. It worked but was a bit wonky.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep in mind that hashes only preserve insertion order, and otherwise they have no intrinsic ordering at all. Altering the hash can scramble the order randomly. It's generally best to store sequences where ordering is important as arrays.

Comment: @tadman That is why I'm using the `each_with_index` as it's my understand that will preserve the order of the hash.

Comment: What I'm saying is when you assume a hash is in a particular order you're in for a surprise when it isn't. Arrays don't mix themselves up this way.

Comment: @tadman I understand what you are saying and read about that fact earlier.    I found that trying just `each` or even `map` then the hash was not in the order created.  That was the only way, at least in my problem, that the order is preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
myhash.values.each_cons(2).find { |pair| pair.first * pair.last == 748 }
```

- values => extract just the values from the hash (so we have an array, no more keys)
- each_cons(2) => I want a new array with pairs of each two adjacent items
- find => find the pair in the array that matches the expression and return that or get `nil` otherwise

Comment: that works great! For me, something to learn from as I have no idea exactly what it is saying but I'll figure it out.  Thank you!

Comment: refactor your block to `{ |a,b| a * b == 748 }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 no I can't seem to make that work. All conditions are false and empty array at the end. Tried a few variations.

Comment: Stuart, please re-check @sagarpandya82's suggestion. It is correct and, imo, a slight improvement in readability.

Comment: I agree, what version of ruby are you in Stuart? I just ran his suggestion correctly as far back as 1.9.3-p125 ( I don't think my Mac will let me install anything earlier for testing)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an enumerator.

```
def doit(arr, target)
  enum = arr.to_enum
  loop { return true if enum.next * enum.peek == target }
  false
end

doit [1,2,3,4,5], 12
  #=> true
doit [1,2,3,4,5], 13
  #=> false
```

[Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) raises a `StopIteration` exception when it attempts to generate a value after [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) has generated the last value. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking out of the loop.

To return the first two consecutive numbers whose product equals the specified value, else `nil`, modify the above as follows.

```
def doit(arr, target)
  enum = arr.to_enum
  loop do
    n = enum.next
    p = enum.peek
    return [n, p] if n*p == target
  end
  nil
end

doit [1,2,3,4,5], 12
  #=> [3, 4]
doit [1,2,3,4,5], 13
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Neatly done, super duper. Note to others, the order of multiplication is important so `enum.peek * enum.next` would not suffice.

Comment: I got the hash converted to enum.  Problem though is getting it to grab the actual multiplied values that match the target. This is what I ran into when trying the `h[v] and h[v+1]`.

Comment: Just to elaborate further I only want the numbers returned when the match is made. In my earlier experiments I found it returning an array of the numbers It did that fine but continued spitting out the same array till the iteration was over.  I keep wanting to use the 'when' to say just return those values that when multiplied match the target.  Of course 'when' doesn't work in this context.

Comment: Stuart, I did an edit to return what you did indeed ask for in the question.